# Generating a URL in a template that takes project URLconf into account

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working through the [Django 1.4 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/), and I notice that in the view layer, URLs are assembled by hand:

```
<form action="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote/" method="post">
```

And so on.

However, on the controller side, URLs are generated dynamically:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls.views.results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Something seems a little inconsistent about this.  Since the prefix for the URL (`/polls` in this case) is determined in the project's URLconf instead of the application's URLconf, it seems unwise to hard-code this value in the template.

Is there a helper or some other way to generate a URL in a Django template so that it takes the URLconf into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can  use the builtin [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)-tag to avoid hardcoding a path.

For example:

```
{% url 'myapp:view-name' %}
```